# Problem with a complicated program that finds the longest substring in which chars are in alphabetical order

Tags: python

I found this solution which seems to work :

```
def longest_ascending(s):
matches = []
current = [s[0]]
for index, character in enumerate(s[1:]):
    if character >= s[index]:
        current.append(character)
    else:
        matches.append(current)
        current = [character]
matches.append(current)
return "".join(max(matches, key=len))
```

print(longest_ascending(s))

Aren't character and indexed s always the same characters ?

For example if 'ababc' was stored in the s variable, the first ''for'' iteration would go over ''if 'b'>=s[1]'', which basically is ''if 'b'>='b''', the second one would contain the statement ''if 'a'>='a''' and so on, which means the ''else'' block would never actually get executed.

So, how exactly does the program function the way it does ?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you are enumerating `s[1:]`, but indexing `s`. If s is '`abc`', then the first pair out of the enumeration is `(0, 'b')`, and `s[0]` is `'a'`.

Comment: How am I indexing s thought ? Both index and character are applied to s[1:], or so I thought it is how the enumerate function works. What did I get wrong ?

Comment: If `s` is `'abc'`, then `s[1:]` will be `'bc'`, and `enumerate(s[1:])` will return `[(0, 'b'), (1, 'c')]`, so `s[index]` will pick out `s[0]` and `s[1]`, which are `'a'` and `'b'`.